# Bound/Covered By Snow

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have this question about the phrase "bound by snow" [here](http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/11/21/usa-weather-idUSL2N0TB1BF20141121):

> Warm temperatures and rain were forecast for the weekend in the city of Buffalo and western New York, bringing the threat of widespread flooding to the ***region bound for days by deep snow***.

How does a region get "***bound*** *by snow*"?  Would "***covered*** *by snow*" be better?

Answer (score 3):

'Bound' implies no-one can get in or out.
The snow is so deep traffic has stopped; roads & schools are closed.

'Covered' just looks pretty ;-)

Bound is presumably from the same root as 'to tie up with rope' - 'Bound by hand & foot', etc. or even 'bound by a promise', 'bound do do his duty'

Comment: *Bound* is tricky as it means both "traveling somewhere"  (*I am homeward bound for Thanksgiving…*) and "unable to travel anywhere" (*…but snowbound at Newark*) depending on usage.

Comment: … or bound for snowbound Newark ;-)